# Destiny: The Taken King - getting to the hangar

Tags: ps3, destiny

I'm playing Destiny: The Taken King on PS3.  When I go to the Hangar, my radar shows markers for a lot of players on the **other** side of the landing plate from the entrance.

I've searched high and low, but the closest I can get is Amanda Holliday's station.  Going up or down to the lounges hasn't been fruitful.

Is the far side of the Hangar not available with this particular game pak?  If not, what's the trick?

Thanks!

Edit:

Here's a photo of what I'm seeing.
[image]

There's a chevron in the radar that suggests there's a kiosk somewhere on the far side of the hangar, behind Holliday and slightly to the right of the POV.  Just walking along the first catwalk overlooking the landing area has the radar showing lots of things (mostly droids, I assume, I forgot they showed on the radar when I originally posted), but the chevron beyond Holliday suggests there's access.  Also, the map from whereisxur.com as of the posting date showed it in some area of the hangar that didn't match my accessible map.

No, as you can see, I'm facing Holliday directly.  I chose her as a reference because she's farther that direction than the quartermaster.

Thanks again!

Comment: Can you share an image of the icons you are seeing and the area you are trying to access?

Comment: I just logged into Destiny on my PS4 and did not find or see anyone across the hanger from Holiday's station.

Comment: If you mean in the direction she is facing and you see nameplates through the wall, you're looking at folks in the vanguard meeting room.

Comment: As shown in the screencap, I am facing *her* and so the top of the radar should be showing things behind her.  Of course, I'm on PS3 and I don't know of any map or coödonate system I can reference, so it just looks to me like the icons are for things on the floor of the Hangar behind her.